# Configuring Azure AD openid with spring security only for authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure Spring Security OpenID Connect with Azure AD but only for **authentication**, **without** calling any `tokenEndpoint` or `userInfoEndpoint`.

I have successfully initiated the authentication flow for OpenID and I see in the network traffic that AzureAD properly redirects to the `redirect_uri` along with the `code` **query parameter** (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure?code=0.AAAA3...`). This `code` is supposed to be read by Microsoft's `MSAL4j` library, verified using the Azure AD public keys and then have the `JWT` extracted which contains the `claims` etc.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to configure the Spring Security Azure filters to look for the token in the URI instead of trying to call a `tokenEndpoint`. I'm obviously getting the following error:

> MsalServiceException: AADSTS240002: Input id_token cannot be used as 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' grant.

And I'm guessing it's because I haven't enabled the `ID Token` flag in my Azure AD configuration which I don't want to enable (since my application does the authentication on the server side). It also says that it is trying to use the `on_behalf_of` `requested_token_use` which I think I don't want (it's part of the authorization which I don't need).

How can I configure Azure AD Spring Security to allow for **authentication** via the `?code=...` query parameter which contains the JWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue you need to enable [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) in your application ,

Please set `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` and `oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow` to **true** in [app manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest) of the application.